# Remove unicode [u']

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode-string

I have this string, input from a webpage.

```
s = "[u'967208', u'411600', u'460273']"
```

I want to remove the brackets `[ ]` and `u` and `'`.

I would also like to make `new line breaks` instead of the commas `,`.

I have spent much time searching for a solution, including encoding and regex, but I can't seem to get it working.

*Updated*: This is what I use to retrieve the string:

```
import selenium
import re
input = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")
s = re.findall("((?<=\()[0-9]*)", input.text)
```

Comment: first question is why is this list a string?

Comment: If you have that as a single string in the first place, as opposed to as an array of strings, you're Doing It Wrong.

Comment: @bmhkim Good questions but I'm a newbie so not sure what you're getting at. I'm getting the input from a https site, yes.

Comment: I hope you trust that website to not be malicious (or taken over by someone who is). The easy approach, using `eval()`, has serious security risks.

Comment: If you have control over the webpage's content, there might be better data encodings than what you're using -- JSON comes to mind.

Comment: @aschmid00 It comes from a text source, so it's a string from the beginning. Should I convert it to numerical instead?

Comment: is the content always digits? or could it be chars too? i suggest you update the code a little more to show how you are getting this data.

Comment: The concern, again, isn't just whether it's malicious but whether it's potentially taken over by someone who's malicious. Someone attacking a piece of infrastructure is going to look for ways to leverage that to get into other infrastructure as well. Resources from a successful attack get leveraged into other attacks; hence the need for defense in depth.

Comment: @aschmid00 Yes, the content will always be digits. I updated the question with more info on the string retrieval.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've been coding for three days so unfortunately those considerations are beyond my abilities. I just need to get rid of the unwanted characters. But if you have any recommendations on security I'd be happy to take them.

Comment: @Winterflags, can you provide the html you are parsing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, sorry. I get the string from a javascript search box. I just grab the string content by the class identifier. When I print it, it always comes in the format [u'xxxx', u'xxxx', u'xxxx']. I think the "u's" must have something to do with Unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the digits with `re` just use `\d+`:

```
import re

s = "[u'967208', u'411600', u'460273']"
print "\n".join(re.findall(r"\d+", s))
967208
411600
460273
```

It is safe and efficient:

```
In [7]: timeit "\n".join(literal_eval(s))
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.7 µs per loop

In [8]: r = re.compile(r"\d+")

In [9]: timeit "\n".join(r.findall(s))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 µs per loop
```

If your goal is to write each string to a file, you can use the csv module to write the list of strings returned from re.findall, using a newline as the delimiter:

```
s = u"[u'967208', u'411600', u'460273']"

import csv
import re
with open("out.csv","w") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out,delimiter="\n")
    r = re.compile("\d+")
    wr.writerow(r.findall(s))
```

Output:

```
967208
411600
460273
```

If you have many strings just iterate calling call r.findall and pass the result to writerow.

I think after the comments the mystery is solved, you had a list of digits all along that was returned from your regex using findall so you can do the following:

```
u"abc(967208) \n abc2(411600) \n abc3(460273)" # input.text

import csv
import re
with open("out.csv","w") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out,delimiter="\n")
    r = re.compile("\((\d+)\)")
    wr.writerow(r.findall(input.text))
```

`\((\d+)\)` will find 1+ digits inside parens.

Comment: you beat me by a second i was just going to submit when i saw ur answer!!

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham: I use regex "((?<=()[0-9]*)" now but could use \d+ instead. However, I still get the output in this format: ['u:xxxx','u:xxxx','u:xxxx']. Has it got something to do with Unicode?

Comment: findall returns an actual list,  with just the string digits inside, I would not worry about the `u`. What are you going to do with the strings? If you can add the html there might be an easier approach

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I output the list to a textfile. Ideally I want each number on a new row, so I can easily copy/paste into a spreadsheet. I only need the numbers, not the non-digits.

Comment: easiest way is to simply use the regex provided and pass the result to csv.writer, I will add the code, what version of python?

Comment: Thanks Padraic! This is for Python 2.7.

Comment: I copied your csv solution, but I'm getting this:     wr.writerow(r.findall(s))
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a string to findall? does `input.text` actually look like you have in your question?

Comment: Yes, everything is identical (though I have substitute variable names in my code, but I have double checked these). The input must be a string because I can successfully print the content, which includes non-digits before I remove the non-digits with regex "((?<=\()[0-9]*)". Note that I use the suffix ".text" – if that has any effect to note. How can I verify that it is a string, or otherwise convert it to a proper string?

Comment: how are you using `((?<=()[0-9]*`)? Can you show me what `input.text` looks like?

Comment: Input.text is: 
`abc(967208) \n
abc2(411600) \n
abc3(460273)`

Gives `s = [u'967208', u'411600', u'460273']`

When trying to pass `s` on to the csv function (and other solutions I have tried, I get malformed string errors. Btw thanks!

Comment: no worries, lol I think you are misinterpreting what you have, you don't have string you have an actual list, pass s directly to csv and I bet it will work

Comment: You were right, that worked like a charm! Sorry about that, I've only been coding for three days, couldn't even use the terminal before then :) Thanks so much for your attention!

Comment: No prob, we all started somewhere :)

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[u'967208', u'411600', u'460273']"
>>> a = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> print(*a, sep='\n')
967208
411600
460273
```

Comment: Nice! I hadn't been aware that `literal_eval()` existed, but per the docs it's a good fit to the task.

Comment: I get this error, copied your solution:

in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on Python 3.4.2 or 2.7.9.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I must be doing something wrong when I grab the "string" with webdriver.find_element_by_class_name and then do regex s = re.findall("((?<=\()[0-9]*)", input.text). Not sure why I get a malformed string.

Comment: When you do `type(s)`, does it say `<class 'str'>`? What does `print(s)` produce? How about `repr(s)`?

Comment: Solved it thanks to @Padraic Cunningham. Turns out that re.findall wasn't creating a string but an actual list. That's why string manipulations didn't work, doh...